# background image is appearing on top of foreground image in Opera and Chrome

Tags: html, css, background-image

I've a tiny span with a background image. This background image scrolls below foreground image. While this works perfectly in IE and FF, it doesn't work in Opera and chrome.

I've put my example [here](http://grayicon.yolasite.com/). PLease see the block with 4 small rectangles.

PLease suggest solution.

Comment: it works in IE8 - compatibility mode.  In 'plain' IE8, it's as broken as in chrome.  This hints in the direction of misinterpretation of the box model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `display:block` to your span.

```
<span style="display:block; background: url(&quot;/resources/images/strength_bgr.gif&quot;) no-repeat scroll 0pt -20px transparent;">
  <img alt="test" src="/resources/images/strength.gif">
</span>
```

Inline elements do not have a height or width so the whole background is being displayed instead of being cropped by the image size.

---

Edit after comments

Is there any reason you can't apply the background image to the img tag itself? That would be more consistent cross-browser.

Comment: @Emily: While your solution works great in FF, Opera and Safari, it breaks in IE6 and IE7. (I don't have IE8).

Comment: @Emily: How about using 'inline-block' instead of 'block'?

Comment: @Emily: "apply the background image to the img tag" worked. Thanks.